# How can I change my MySQL timezone to Indian timezone?

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services

I am currently working on project and I have seen that my `MySQL database` is showing timezone of UTC. I have changed the timezone from AWS to `Asia/Calcutta` and when I rechecked that it has been changed or not, it is showing the timezone which I have set. But the problem arises when I am inserting or updating any data then the time is showing in `UTC timezone`. I can't understand what the problem is.

Comment: Databases should always use UTC. Is there a reason you're wanting to use a local timezone? How will you handle possible future legislative changes to the `Asia/Calcutta` timezone definition? You'll need to retroactively update all of your previous data to be correct with the new legal definition of the Calcutta timezone - and that's a non-trivial task.

Comment: But my client wants the time in Indian timezone.

Comment: With all due respect, your client is not making a good choice. It's better to store dates in UTC, and convert them to the user's preference of timezone in the application presentation. This makes it easier to support users in different timezones, or even any individual user who wants to change their timezone preference when they travel!

Comment: But if they insist, you can change the timezone of a MySQL instance. The documentation is here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/time-zone-support.html

Comment: The timezone is often changed by SQL clients. So, when you are viewing the contents of a date field, it might not actually be the value that is stored in the database. You can test this by casting it into a string before retrieving the value.

Comment: @BillKarwin I have done all these things but still the changes is not reflected.